# Add the IMBD rating to my web site / HTML

Tags: javascript, html, imdb

I'm using HTML to create a film review site and trying to add the IMDB rating.

I'm using this code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="rating-row" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope 
    itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <a class="icon" href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7126948/" title="IMDb 
        Rating" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://yts.mx/assets/images/website/logo-imdb.svg" alt="IMDb Rating" />  
    </a>
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">5.5</span>
    <span itemprop="bestRating" style="display: none;">10</span>
    <span itemprop="ratingCount" style="display: none;">135549</span>
    <span class="hidden-xs icon-star"></span>
</div>
</html>
```

It gives me the IMDB logo and the rating next to it, but I don't know how to make the rating **auto-refresh** when its value changes on the IMDB website.

In the code I put the value 5.5 **manually**. Is there a way to automize the process?

PS: I'm new to HTML, I just started using it.

Comment: This isn't something you can do in just html. This 'auto-refresh' thing. Depending on your needs, you'll either have to implement some sort of api consumer in javascript on the client side, or you may have to build a backend to support the features you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't automatize it using only HTML, you will need to use PHP or Javascript (AJAX) and request directly to the IMDB website API.
So whenever you're accessing the webpage you ask to the website **What is the rating ?** the **IMDB API** send you the current rating and you display the value into your HTML.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. And do you have any resources I could use? I'm new to this and I'm not sure where to start...

Comment: First you have to choose between php or javascript, I feel like php is easier but it's up to you. You have different options either you read the documentation at [https://www.php.net/](php.net) and try by yourself by playing around or you can learn from youtube, codecademy etc... For your problem I think trying to use an API is too hard to begin with so here's a post to learn a bit about HTML and PHP. This way of proceeding is not recommended but it's good to understand the mechanism [https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-php-in-html-code--cms-34378](Here).

Answer (score -1):

Html only determines how to display the document(i.e on Browser). You have to use an **asynchronous development environment** to Auto-Reload the value on change.
Even **JS is synchronous**(means that only one operation can be in progress at a time), so you have to use AJAX to make JS asynchronous(to call ).
Only with HTML, you can't make the Page content Auto-Refresh.
And Yes there are multiple ways by which You can Automize this process but you have to use Asynchronous technology.
You should refer to this for understanding
[Asynchronous](https://www.theserverside.com/news/1363576/What-is-the-Asynchronous-Web-and-How-is-it-Revolutionary)

Comment: The link you provide is wildly unhelpful when it comes to solving the problem.

Comment: Ajax does not make JS asynchronous. It's a buzzword meaning "Make an HTTP request with JavaScript" and is makes use of one of a section of the many asynchronous APIs available to JS programs.